# how can I find news article dataset for text summarization?

Tags: text, nlp, dataset, evaluation, summarization

I want to summarize some news article.I need a dataset. 
There is BBC dataset but the problem is that I cant evaluate my output with others.

Comment: what do you mean by you can't evaluate your output with others

Answer (score 1):

This dataset can be used for your text summarizations tasks and check your output with the given output.

https://www.kaggle.com/sunnysai12345/news-summary/data

if you need a news articles dataset this can be useful.

http://research.signalmedia.co/newsir16/signal-dataset.html (one million news articles dataset)

Comment: thank u so much. but I want to use extractive summarization for my project. the kaggle summarization is abstractive. can I use abstractive summaries instead of extractive summaries for evaluation?

Comment: https://tac.nist.gov//2011/Summarization/Guided-Summ.2011.guidelines.html and http://duc.nist.gov/data.html  http://multiling.iit.demokritos.gr/pages/view/1532/task-mss-single-document-summarization-data-and-information